# iCloud data Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, icloud

i want to save NSInteger to iCloud when the view controller is loaded. I've tried save NSInteger data to iCloud, but i fail to do so. I therefore convert it to NSNumber instead. So the problem is when i try to save the NSNumber to iCloud, it fails with an error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key coins cloud.'

here is the code i used

```
 NSInteger currentValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                             integerForKey:@"coins.demo"];

   NSNumber *currentvalue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:currentValue];

   NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore *cloudStore = [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore];

   [cloudStore setValue:currentvalue forKey:@"coinscloud"];

   [cloudStore synchronize];


   NSNumber *cloudcoins = [cloudStore valueForKey:@"coinscloud"];

   _coinLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)]coinscloud];
```

I will appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Use `-setObject:forKey:` (`NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`) instead:

```
[cloudStore setObject:/* <-- */ currentvalue forKey:@"coinscloud"];
```

BTW:

```
NSInteger currentValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                         integerForKey:@"coins.demo"];
```

Are you really sure that you want to use a *key*, not *key path* of `coins.demo`?

Comment: i get another error for using setObject. the error "Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending NSInteger aka long to parameter of type id

Comment: `currentvalue`, not `currentValue`. But you should really recheck your naming.